# How do I get the index of the common integer element from two separate lists and plug it to another list?

Tags: python

---

I have 3 lists.

```
A_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

```
Q_act = [2, 3]
```

```
dur = [0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 8, 2, 3]
```

All lists are integers.

What I am trying to do is to compare `Q_act` with `A_set` then obtain the indices of the numbers that match from `A_set`.

(Example: 
`Q_act` has the elements `[2,3]`
it is located in indices `[1,2]` from `A_set`)

Afterwards, I will use those indices to obtain the corresponding value in `dur` and store this in a list called `p_dur_Q_act`.

(Example: using the result from the previous example, `[1,2]`

The values in the `dur` list corresponding to the indices `[1,2]` should be stored in another list called `p_dur_Q_act`

i.e. `[4,5]` should be the values stored in the list `p_dur_Q_act`)

So, how do I get the index of the common integer element (which is `[1,2]`) from two separate lists and plug it to another list?

---

So far here are the code(s) I used:

This one, I wrote because it returns the index. But not `[4,5]`.

```
p_Q = set(Q_act).intersection(A_set)
    p_dur_Q_act = [i + 1 for i, x in enumerate(p_Q)]
    print(p_dur_Q_act)
```

I also tried this but I receive an error `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`

```
 p_dur_Q_act = [i + 1 for i, x in enumerate(Q_act) if any(elem in x for elem in A_set)]
    print(p_dur_Q_act)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the `enumerate` iterator to generate every index, and then select only the ones you want:

```
a_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
q_act = [2, 3]    
dur = [0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 8, 2, 3]

p_dur_q_act = [i for i,v in enumerate(a_set) if v in q_act]

print([dur[p] for p in p_dur_q_act if p in dur]) # [4, 5]
```

This is more efficient than repeatedly calling index if the number of matches is large, because the number of calls is proportional to the number of matches, but the duration of calls is proportional to the length of a_set.  The enumerate approach can be made even more efficient by turning q_act into a set, since `in` scales better with sets than lists.  At these scales, though, there will be no observable difference.

You don't need to map these to index values, though.  You can get the same result if you use `zip` to map `a_set` to `dur` and then select the `d` values whose `a` values are in `q_act`.

```
a_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
q_act = {2, 3}    
dur = [0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 8, 2, 3]

p_dur_q_act = [d for a, d in zip(a_set, dur) if a in q_act]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list) function to get the index of the element in the list.

```
>>> a_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> q_act = [2, 3]
>>> dur = [0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 8, 2, 3]
>>>
>>> print([dur[a_set.index(q)] for q in set(a_set).intersection(q_act)])

[4, 5]
```

Comment: I would use sets to make it a bit more explicit in the list comp: p_dur_q_act = [a_set.index(q) for q in set(a_set)&set(q_act)]

Comment: I receive this <generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000255A5FA8C10> what does it mean?

Comment: @AJGayeta, u might have missed ``[]`` brackets inside print statement.

Comment: I took the same code, now it returns only [ ] hmm I’m confused

Comment: @AJGayeta, checkout the updated answer seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time in answering @Sushanth I highly appreciate it!